# I'm writing a code on flutter to Sign In with Google but I got this error at the first hand

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-signin

## Error:

```
lib/Connection/inregistrare.dart:372:44: Error: Required named parameter 'label' must be provided.
                        ElevatedButton.icon(
                                           ^
../../../AppData/Local/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart:88:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  factory ElevatedButton.icon({
          ^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
 
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\iduet\AppData\Local\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\iduet\AppData\Local\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 
BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              4,5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[here](https://pastebin.com/q0kCWuSw) there is a paste bin beacuse the code is badly formatted

If you can find more problems with my code please tell me.

I've watched 5 tutorials and still I couldn't make it work :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the widget you are using needs a label parameter as required but I’m not sure, I can help if you can just add the widget that you are using

`Edit`:

Just now saw the paste bin, you were giving the `labelStyle` inside the decoration of `TextFormField` but didn’t give the label parameter

So you can either remove the `labelStyle` or adding a `label` will fix this problem

Please refer to the fixed code

```
TextFormField(
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _ChangeColor00();
                  });
                },
                focusNode: f1,
                onTap: _ChangeColor1,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                obscureText: _vizibility,
                controller: _passwordValue0,
                // textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _toggleVizibility,
                    child: Icon(
                      _vizibility ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                      color: culoare1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  label: Text('Something'), //<-- Here
                  labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.lock,
                    color: culoare1,
                  ),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
                  floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  // filled: true,
                  // fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
```

`label` - When the input field is empty and unfocused, the label is displayed on top of the input field

`labelStyle` - The style to use for `[InputDecoration.labelText]` when the label is on top of the input field.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, it worked but now I have another bug, https://pastebin.com/41DvBRek

Comment: In the 59th line of your paatebin code you have to return the child that you are passing to the ChangeNotifierProvider function

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to fix that, this is my first flutter project. Could you be more specifix with what I shoul fix?

Comment: Fixed code please check
`ChangeNotifierProvider(
    {required GoogleSignInProvider Function(dynamic context) create,
    required MaterialApp child}) { 
          return child;
 }`